# making a search.php query

Tags: php, wp-query, search, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a custom search results page.  I want there to be 6 posts at a time, and then I am going to add in a load more button that will load 6 more and so on.  I want the page to be in a bootstrap grid layout.  With 2 posts per line (col-md-6).  With the code below, the web page wont even show up.  Do I need to add anything to my functions.php to make this work?  Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```html
<?php 

get_header(); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 6, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 


<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { 
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
get_footer();
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a separate WP_Query - search.php will already return results for the search by default. I'd strip it down to just `get_header(); get_footer();` to start out. If that works, add in your page-level wrapping HTML. If that works, add a loop inside - `if(have_posts()) { while(have_posts()): the_post();` and start tweaking its HTML output. If none of these work, turn on WP_DEBUG and/or check your error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the search parameter in your arguments. The code below, when added to the array in `$the_query`, should pass along the query string variable from a search:

`'s' => $s`

Documentation is available here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter